# Refresh ajax-data in callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, selectize.js

Good Day. Can you give me an advice how to refresh data from server in my callback function? For example, I receive from server some list of names (an array of objects. Object consists of id, name, and some counter of this created objects on the page). And when I load page this list creates. But, If I create new item on my page(no matter how), I want to refresh data(for example on 'refresh-btn' click ) from server, to see true count of objects on my page.(Now the true count of objects users will see only if they reload the page). So I need to refresh data inside my callback function.

```
getCategoryAdCount: function (callback) {
    var that = this,
    dataToSend = {
        method: 'getCategoryAdCount',
        params: {
            productId: this.productId
        }
    };

   SJA.ajax(dataToSend, function (respond) {
        if (respond) {
            callback && callback(respond);
        }
       console.log(respond);
       //always gives true refreshed data. If I add item, we will see it in console. So the problem is in the callback function below
    });
};
```

My callback:

```
$(document).ready(
    this.getCategoryAdCount(function (categories) { 
        //this function I call when page loads.
         var values = categories.map(function (cat) {return { item : cat.id, text : cat.name + ' (' +cat.count + ')'}; }); 
          //Data from server This data I want to refresh. 
          console.log(values) 
          //always gives only initial result. If I add new item, we won't see it in console. 

    console.log(categories);
   $('.filter').selectize({
      plugins: ['remove_button'],
      delimiter: ',',
      persist: false,
      maxItems: 5,
      options: values,
      labelField: "text",
      valueField: "item",
      sortField: 'text',
      searchField: 'text',
      create: function(input) {
        return {
          value: input,
          text: input
        }
      }
    });
    }.bind(this));

    $('.refresh-btn').on('click', function(){}) //This is an event, on which I want to refresh data in function above. 
)};
```

Comment: It's not fully clear what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you just need to declare the `categories` variable within scope of both code blocks.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sorry, added some information to the question

Comment: possible you are talking about _pull notification_?

Comment: Just get the data using ajax and then call that `getCategoryAdCount` function and pass categories to it.